# Paypal // Wix // Quickbooks

Tags: paypal, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, velo

I'm a designer who's working for a client on the Wix platform. They have a youth choir which parents need to register their children for every year. They also use Quickbooks as their accounting software, and in the past have had an issue with their Paypal and Quickbook integrations failing because of the lack of a static datapoint.

Ex. Josh Smith might sign up his daughter Alice for the choir. Alice is a step daughter, so her name, email, phone number, etc. are all different than the father's. The payment goes through, and Quickbooks doesn't know how to connect the Father's payment and signup info to Alice's name in their system, so it becomes essentially a data dump. Josh Smith paid X amount, and Alice is in Quickbooks, but it can't connect them if he pays through paypal - because paypal isn't grabbing the fields from Wix that it needs to be grabbing (because I don't know how to set them up). It's only integrating the fields automatically populating through Paypal.

If anyone has any clue what I'm talking about, I would appreciate the assistance of how I can force ALL form fields to be registered by paypal, so that they're registered in Quickbooks.

Comment: What form component are you using?

Comment: @MoshFeu I've tried a bunch - but in a perfect world I'd just be able to use the native Wix forms provided.

Comment: I'm not familiar with quickbooks and I didn't use Paypal for a long time but I can help you with getting the form data when the user submits it. Then you can make calls to paypal or quickbox whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

To associate Josh Smith's payment with his step-daughter's customer record in QuickBooks, designate Alice's customer account (in QuickBooks) as a "sub-customer" of Josh Smith.

1. Tick the "Is sub-customer" checkbox in her profile
2. Select Josh Smith as the "parent customer"
3. Choose "Bill with parent" from the dropdown to the right of that

Next time an invoice is created for Alice's membership fee, select **Alice** as the customer and send it to Josh Smith. In QuickBooks, it will show that Josh is responsible for paying Alice's membership fee, and her membership will show as paid once Josh makes the payment (in PayPal, or wherever).

[Designating a QuickBooks customer as a sub-customer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqSqO.png)